# 2 Way Databind components within Components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am struggling to reuse my components.

I want to pass the data passed to my component as a prop to another component.
If I do that vue complains about a mutation of the prop.

Example:
I have contacts that I want to show on multiple location of my app.
For that I created a contact component to reuse it:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <input :value="contact.firstName" @input="$emit('update:contact', {...contact, firstName: $event.target.value})">
        <Mother v-model:mother="contact.mother"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Mother from '@/components/Mother'

export default {
  name: 'Contact',
  components: {
    Mother
  },
  props: {
    contact: Object,
  },
  emit: ['update:contact'],
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>
```

Every contact has a mother, mother are shown in other places not only in the contact component.
That is why I created a mother component, that is used by the contact.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <input :value="mother.lastName" @input="$emit('update:mother', {...mother, lastName: $event.target.value})">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Mother',
  props: {
    mother: Object,
  },
  emit: ['update:mother'],
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>
```

Now I want to be able to mutate the contact an the mother as well, and I want to be able to use two contact components on the same site.

If I use it the way explained I get this error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                  09:17:25

 error  in ./src/components/Contact.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

/tmp/vue-example/src/components/Contact.vue
  4:27  error  Unexpected mutation of "contact" prop  vue/no-mutating-props

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

I have an example project showing my problem:
https://gitlab.com/FirstWithThisName/vue-example.git

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your project is working. Write in more detail what you can't do

Comment: No it is not, if you try to run it with npm run serve you get the error 'Unexpected mutation of "contact" prop'

Comment: Exactly what it says, you cannot mutate a props. You should look into "modelValue" props that automatically passed in when using v-model. And keep track of updated value using watch/computed property instead of mutate the prop directly. Also I don't see the reason of chaining 2 input component, why not split into 2 different component into "App.vue" instead?

Comment: @Cerceis to reuse the chained component in another place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I need to assume a few points.

- You wanted to use v-model.
- You wanted the component to be chained.

Working Example [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) on Vue SFC Playground.
*Note that the import path is different on the example site.

### App.vue

```
<template>
    <Contact v-model="contact" />
    {{ contact }}
</template>
... remaining code omitted
```

### Contact.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="localValue"/>
        <Mother v-model="childValue" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Mother from "./Mother.vue"
export default {
    name: "Contact",
    components: {
        Mother
    },
    props: {
        modelValue: Object,
    },
    mounted(){
        this.childValue = this.modelValue.mother
    },
    data: () => ({
        localValue: "",
        childValue: null
    }),
    watch:{
        updatedData(){
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.updatedData)
        }
    },
    computed: {
        updatedData() {
            return { firstName: this.localValue, mother: this.childValue };
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

### Mother.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input
            v-model="localValue"
            @input="$emit('update:modelValue', updatedData)"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Mother",
    props: {
        modelValue: Object,
    },
    data: () => ({
        localValue: "",
    }),
    computed: {
        updatedData() {
            return { ...this.modelValue, lastName: this.localValue };
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

As you might know, `props` cannot be mutated, so you will need to "make a copy" of the value on each component to process locally.

If `Mother` component are never going to be used separately, v-model can be split into `v-on` and `v-bind` instead.

Lastly, as for recommendation, chaining like this can become very messy if the data starts to grow or the depth level increases. You could just make another `Wrapper` component that contains `Contact` and `Mother` component that scales horizontally instead.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how complex your application will get.
One option is two-way data-binding as explained here:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#using-v-model-on-components

So you basically `emit` the changes to the parent.

For more complex applications I wouldn't pass data that are used in multiple components as props, but use a store. Either a simple reactive object; with [`provide/inject`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity) or use something like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

Comment: I can't pass emit twice, or I don't know how.
I think vuex is not the right choice, isn't it made for global state management? Provide/Inject seams bad to me too because I have to hard code the name, so I can't use my component twice in the same parent.

Comment: @AceofSpade What is the problem with emit twice? If you already tried to do this, showing this in the question may help to fix it, instead of explaining the whole concept from scratch.