v-bind equivalent of modelValue
I've got a myInput.vue component which accepts a v-model prop and captures the value of v-model as modelValue, like so:
<template>
  <input type="text" :value="modelValue" />
</template>

<script setup>
  const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: {
      type: [String, null],
      required: true
    }
  })
</script>

If I'm using v-bind as opposed to v-model, how would I go about capturing the value from within the component? Using bindValue doesn't work.

Please clarify more

@BoussadjraBrahim v-model doesn't work inside slots. I'm using VeeValidate for form validation and it works with slots and v-bind for this matter.

Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70079530/2-way-databind-components-within-components/70301542#70301542

What about using the defineModel macro :
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="modelValue" />
</template>

<script setup>
const modelValue = defineModel()
</script>


Available from Vue 3.3+

@TobiasBraun yes and stable from 3.4

As far as I understand, you need to emit an event in the child component and catch it in the parent component.
You can do it like this:
<template>
  <input type="text" :value="modelValue" @input="updateValue" />
</template>

<script setup>
  const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: {
      type: [String, null],
      required: true
    }
  });

  const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);

  function updateValue(event) {
    emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value);
  }
</script>

There are two ways to use this component:
<my-input :modelValue="text” @update:modelValue="(newValue) => text.value = newValue" />

or
<my-input v-model="text" />

I'm assuming that text is a ref variable.
It's worth remembering that v-model is basically just an add-on to v-bind and v-on, here's a more detailed description: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#basic-usage.
